# How do I save an image after modifying it

Tags: java, android

I can load the picture to the background then I have also been able to "sketchify" it but when I try to save it so that I can email it as an attachment I can only figure out haw to grab the original image and what I have here makes the activity close

```
public void startCamera(View v) {
        Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        seek.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (takePicture.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

            picSpot = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "sketch.png");

            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(picSpot);
            takePicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(takePicture, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    public void sendPic(View v) {
        Intent sharePic = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        if (didsketch == false) {

            sharePic.setType("image/png");
            sharePic.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, outputFileUri);
            sharePic.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Check This Out!");
            sharePic.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    "I did this on my Sketchify App!");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharePic, "Send Email"));
        } else {
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(finalSpot);
                back.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(finalSpot);
            sharePic.setType("image/png");
            sharePic.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, outputFileUri);
            sharePic.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Check This Out!");
            sharePic.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    "I did this on my Sketchify App!");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharePic, "Send Email"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        sketchit.setEnabled(true);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
            screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
            location = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/sketch.png";
            back = Camera_Helpers.processImage(location, screenHeight,
                    screenWidth);
            taken = true;
            sketchit.setEnabled(taken);
            shareit.setEnabled(taken);
            image.setImageBitmap(back);
        }
    }
```

back is the modified bitmap i am trying to eventually attach to the email
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create Folder Directory and Save image into it:** create directory where you want to save your images. Suppose the folder name is **ImageFolder**.

```
String location = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ImageFolder/";

//Creating Folder Directory 
File imageDir = new File(location);
dir.mkdirs();

//Creating Image file
String imageName = "sketch.png";

File imageFile = new File(imageDir, imageName);

//If image file already exists then delete it.
if (imageFile.exists()) {
    imageFile.delete();
}

//Writing the image to SDCard
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    back.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```